# How to make the listview items look organized?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-studio

The list view looks so bad. Because of the orgranization. I want to make it better. I mean the colon needs to be position at constant place without moving here and there . So here is my xml code.
and you can see the image it looks so bad 
[image: list view image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="1px"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"

            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/darker_grey"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/darker_grey"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text=":" />

        <TextView
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/darker_grey"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: unable to view image

Comment: @rajanks http://i.stack.imgur.com/DXWGB.png

Comment: please now you can see image

Comment: @bucky I think the only logical step you can take is assuming a constant width for the first column and using the rest of the width for the 2nd column. You can use `layout_weight` to achieve this.

Comment: tried that too but not working ..

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ok, now I got what you need.
Use Relative layout, so you can choose where to position the nested layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/login_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="hi hi"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text=":"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="hey hey"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i just need help in the xml

Comment: Yeah sorry, now I got it, try the solution above

Comment: Your code worked well after a little modification in textview 3 .. I cchanged the width from wrap_content to other value and i wworked.. Thanx for the help ..

Comment: I'm glad it worked, i used wrap to not take too much space, but of course you can change it to whatever fit your needs :)

Comment: :) and i can't upvote your answer because i don't have enough reeputation..

Answer (score 0):

Now try this. Hope you'll get what you want.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lyt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/darker_grey"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text=":"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/darker_grey" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/darker_grey"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No it's not working , part of texts are going hidden. and the organization is still bad

Comment: please try to recheck it. I edited my answer. If same error , please feel free to ask.

Comment: http://buckydroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Screenshot_20160615-135922.png after using your code

Comment: i think this may be coz of gravity. first try to remove **android:gravity="left|top"** and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your list item xml looks like this. You should use **weight sum** for your parent layout and set **android:layout_width** to **"match_parent"** for child view with appropriate weight value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="1px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text=":"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```